# 1st form within table not submitting

Tags: php, forms

I have a while loop generated table that looks like the following:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Pushups</th>
    <th>Delete</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>11-01-2012</td>
    <td>28</td>
    <td>
        <form action="../workout_tracker/delete_pushups.php" method="get" id="Delete1">
            <input type="hidden" value="253" name="pushups_id" />
            <input type="hidden" value="/workout_tracker/pushups-tracker/" name="current_page" />
            <input type="submit" value="Delete" form="Delete1" />
        </form>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>11-02-2012</td>
    <td>33</td>
    <td>
        <form action="../workout_tracker/delete_pushups.php" method="get" id="Delete2">
            <input type="hidden" value="246" name="pushups_id" />
            <input type="hidden" value="/workout_tracker/pushups-tracker/" name="current_page" />
            <input type="submit" value="Delete" form="Delete2" />
        </form>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>11-03-2012</td>
    <td>43</td>
    <td>
        <form action="../workout_tracker/delete_pushups.php" method="get" id="Delete3">
            <input type="hidden" value="39" name="pushups_id" />
            <input type="hidden" value="/workout_tracker/pushups-tracker/" name="current_page" />
            <input type="submit" value="Delete" form="Delete3" />
        </form>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

The problem is that the first "Delete" form in the first row of the table isn't submitting. When I click, it doesn't do anything.

There is a form higher up on the page, but it closes and has validated. I get the same response in Chrome, Firefox, and IE.

**UPDATE:**
In a different form higher in the markup (not shown), the form tag had not been closed. I had `</for>`...

Comment: the `form` attribute of an input is unknown to me. Is it a standard attribute?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a difference between the first form and the others. Can you post a fiddle?

Comment: Your form seems to work, you may have some other issues with other forms before this code.

Comment: Post your php code as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do any of the other delete forms work or is it just the first one?

Open up your browser console/debugger and look for any errors on page load or when you click the button.

The only thing that looks as a possible problem is the form attribute of the submit input element. The link below shows that it's new in HTML5 and the only browser that doesn't support it yet is IE. It could be that you need to update to the latest version of your browser.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_form.asp

Comment: If the `form` attribute points to its DOM parent, it's practically a NOP. It should not cause the issue.

Comment: Also, the poster reports the issue in all three major browsers.

Comment: That's what I would assume as well but the form attribute is the only thing looks unusual to me so that's where I'd place most of my suspicions.

Comment: @JanDvorak You're right about the browser. I read that but didn't process it. Its more likely, as Nikos mentions above, a problem with other code on the page.

Comment: I had to clean up the WordPress HTML quite a bit to get any meaningful information out of the W3C validator, but once I had it stripped down to the content, it immediately found that there was an existing form element still opened.